# registering a dll on various OS

Tags: dll, vb6

I have looked through countless threads on the error message
"the module was loaded but the entry-point dllregisterserver was not found make sure that is a valid DLL or OCX file"

I also tried regsvr32, and regsvr32 from syswow64...
I also tried registering it as name.ocx (per another threads suggestion).

```
    Option Explicit On
    Imports System

    Public Class GenThis
        Public Function rtnStr(Optional ByVal o As Object = Nothing) As String
            Try
            'do stuff
                rtnStr = strTmp
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return "ERROR"
            End Try

        End Function
    End Class
```

That is the class, being built on 2.0. When I add the dll as a reference in VS everything works fine. When I try to go in (same machine, Win7) to Excel Dev tab to try and add it there it does not exist. Also need to be bale to register it for our VB6 application.

I can't find any definitive answers or explanations on "what" this means. Can someone elaborate what is going on and what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Not all COM dlls are registerable. Sometimes the registration info sits in another dll. Programming languages use type libraries that may or may not be in the dll. Type libraries and registration is two seperate things.

.NET COM dlls aren't registerable in the normal way (it's the .NET framework that gets registered and it recieves calls and passes them to the .NET COM dll). For .NET use RegAsm, part of the .NET framework, which sets it up.

Comment: The problem is that the DLL needs to be deploy-able to NT OS (yes.... NT)... So I am thinking what I need to do is make the class an COM dll and then register it accordingly regardless of which OS I am on?

Comment: Windows 8 is "NT" so what you are probably trying to say is NT 4.0, NT 3.51, etc.  Starting with Windows 2000 Microsoft started a new naming scheme at the consumer level (Windows 2000 is really NT 5.0).

Comment: What type of dll is it? Is it a .NET one? Use RegAsm which is installed on all computers with the .NET framework installled. Here's a build batch for a simple COM server in VB.NET written using notepad. `"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe" /target:library /out:"%userprofile%\desktop\sendmail\sendmail.dll" "%userprofile%\desktop\sendmail\sendmail.cls" /verbose

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm" /codebase "%userprofile%\desktop\sendmail\sendmail.dll" /tlb:"%userprofile%\desktop\sendmail\sendmail.tlb" /v`

Comment: Yes it's NT 3.5. The dll for xp+ was written in .net, the other one was written in VB6 (just found out). What I was trying to do was build my dll so it would be in one place. I am guessing this is not do-able unless the NT machine has the framework installed :|

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Noodle, it was helpful in my understanding but still doesn't answer the question- which at this point I'm not sure what I am really trying to ask. I need to think on this some. I flagged the question to be deleted/closed for moderator (ie I still have a question, but I'm not sure how to ask it, and need to think on this some).

Comment: Just put it in an install package. User dbl clicks (or it's pushed out). Make your own in VB6 and VB.NET. Choose the options to include frameworks (VB.NET) or runtimes (VB6). Or just install the framework then your program. Type iexpress in start - run for an installer program.